# How to get the output of the command maven

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, xunit

I have following `Jenkinsfile` :

```
node {
  stage('Checkout') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('Build') {
    try {
      sh ''' mvn clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install  > commandResult '''
      def result = readFile('commandResult').trim()
    }
    catch (err) {
      step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1, thresholds: [
        [$class: 'FailedThreshold', failureThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '1'],
        [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
      ], tools: [
        [$class: 'JUnitType', deleteOutputFiles: false, failIfNotNew: false, pattern: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', skipNoTestFiles: true, stopProcessingIfError: false]
      ]])
    }
    finally {
      echo "{$result}"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the plugin `xUnit` to set a threshold of unstable build when some tests failed (in this case, when 1 or more tests fail, the build is marked as unstable). I also want to parse the output of the Maven shell command to mark the build as "failed" if there is a compilation error. If there is no error and all tests passed, proceed to xUnit. How can I do this?

I have tried the answers provided in other questions, but it didn't work in my case. When I try this `Jenkinsfile` above, the build is failing and I don't get the output value.

My Jenkins version is `2.107.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if script passed to `sh` step exists with nonzero exit code, pipeline step fails and exception is thrown. In this case the next line of the code where you read a file does not get executed.

Jenkins' `sh` step supports `returnStatus` option. If you set it to `true` it will make `sh` step return exit code and it wont throw any exception if this exit code is something else than zero. However in this case you have to react if exit code informs you about the error. Consider following example:

```
stage ('Build') {
  def exitCode = sh(script: 'mvn clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install  > commandResult', returnStatus: true)
  def result = readFile('commandResult').trim()

  if (exitCode != 0) {
    // error happened 
    step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1, thresholds: [
      [$class: 'FailedThreshold',  failureThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '1'],
      [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
    ],tools: [
      [$class: 'JUnitType', deleteOutputFiles: false, failIfNotNew: false, pattern: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', skipNoTestFiles: true, stopProcessingIfError: false]
    ]])
  }

  // do something with result
  echo "{$result}"

  // e.g mark build as error
  error 'Maven command failed!'
}
```

> *Reference: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script*

#### Using `mvn --log-file` instead of `>`

You can also try:

```
stage ('Build') {
  def exitCode = sh(script: 'mvn --log-file commandResult clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install', returnStatus: true)
  def result = readFile('commandResult').trim()

  if (exitCode != 0) {
    // error happened 
    step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder', testTimeMargin: '3000', thresholdMode: 1, thresholds: [
      [$class: 'FailedThreshold',  failureThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '1'],
      [$class: 'SkippedThreshold', failureThreshold: '', unstableThreshold: '']
    ],tools: [
      [$class: 'JUnitType', deleteOutputFiles: false, failIfNotNew: false, pattern: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml', skipNoTestFiles: true, stopProcessingIfError: false]
    ]])
  }

  // do something with result
  echo "{$result}"

  // e.g mark build as error
  error 'Maven command failed!'
}
```

Comment: I tried this and the build aborted at reading the file:  `Read file from workspace -- commandResult -- (self time 143ms) `

Comment: Can you paste console log from that build?

Comment: `Stage Logs (Build)
Shell Script (self time 5s)

[jenkins-failure_master-EHKMAGGDJWHA7FNGHQYY2VJNJHBX2RXI3XJY4NU5EB2PYT4ERTZQ] Running shell script
+ mvn clean -B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install

Read file from workspace -- commandResult -- (self time 143ms) `

Comment: and the variable `exitCode`  is equal to 1. I guess the file didn't got created?

Comment: this wont work as when a test fails, the exit code is 1 also.

Comment: You can try using `--log-file` mvn parameter instead of forwarding output to a file. If readFile fails it means that for some reason file creation fails.

Comment: How can I also check if the file contains the following string: `COMPILATION ERROR` ? as the maven command will return 1 code in two cases: some tests are failed , or there is a compilation error, so I need to put another if condition under `if exitCod !=0`

Comment: The `result` variable should contain the output from the console - you can search for specific substring or use regular expression to check if the output contains specific string or pattern.